# Node.js: Русские символы в запросе

Tags: node.js, url, браузер, path, http-status-code-404

Я отсылаю браузеру путь до файла, все работает, картинка отображается, но если в пути встретится папка с русским названием, то все ломается и картинка не отображается. Выскакивает следующая ошибка:
73892c10b1e0c0f2e0c4.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8080/Desktop/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82/7382e0c4.jpg 404 (Not Found)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set({"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
    res.render('index', {images: images, index_img: index_img})
});
```

Comment: русские символы - зло

Comment: @RavenTheX Но, к сожалению, работать с ними приходится